# Either ints in range in one "if" statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Maybe I am swatting flies with a sledgehammer but...

I was doing this exerice on [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p178728);

> Given 2 ints, a and b, return their sum. However, "teen" values in the range [13, 19] are extra lucky. So if either value is a teen, just return 19.

and this is the answer I came up with;

```
public int teenSum(int a, int b)
{
    if (a >= 13 && a <= 19) return 19;
    if (b >= 13 && b <= 19) return 19;
    else return a + b;
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to solve this problem in just one "if" statement... is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a ternary operator (`? :`) you could do it with zero `if` statements. Something like,

```
public int teenSum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > 12 && a < 20) || (b > 12 && b < 20) ? 19 : a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a logically equivalent expression using logical OR:

```
if ((a >= 13 && a <= 19) || (b >= 13 && b <= 19)) return 19;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. By putting two if statements as guard clauses, what you're really doing is a logical OR. So:

```
if ((a >= 13 && a <= 19) || (b >= 13 && b <= 19)) return 19;
```

would also work.

By the way, the `else` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it entirely without `if` statements, using the `?:` ternary operator.

```
return (a >= 13 && a <= 19) || (b >= 13 && b <= 19) ? 19 : a + b;
```